# Multi valued dimension on comma delimited string

Tags: druid

We have a dimension which holds value as a comma delimited string (ex:"t1,t2,t3"), are there possibilities where we can get this dimension treated as a Multi Valued Dimension without storing them as JSON arrays?

Note: If we have to correct them and load as JSON arrays, all the historical data for the past 6 months has to be fixed

Thanks,
Sathish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://druid.io/docs/0.9.1.1/querying/multi-value-dimensions.html), multi-valued fields are generated during data ingestion. So if you have ingested your data as a single coma-delimited string, then the only way to treat it as a multi-value field, is to re-ingest your data. That is, if you want to filter by that value or to use it in "groupBy" queries. If you want just extract sub-portion of the data, then [extraction functions](http://druid.io/docs/0.9.1.1/querying/dimensionspecs.html) can be of use.